# Get Image from Media Library with the Title

Tags: customization, images, media, title, library

i have set the Title from a Image in my MediaLibrary to "slider".

I want to add this Picture via. Code to my page.php file.

I dont want to use the ID, I want to use the Title.
How can i do this?

Thanks 4ur help :D